# Tensorflow: Reverse flattening of a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, flatten

OS: Kubuntu 14.04, Tensorflow version = 0.12, Python version = 2.7

After my last layer the output  of my neural net has the shape`[batch, height, width, 2]` which is `[64, 32, 256, 2]` in my case.

After that I use

```
output = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(input=output)
```

which produces a Tensor with the shape`[64, 16384]`

For evaluation purposes I would like to reverse this flattening in a different function to get the original `[64, 32, 256, 2]` Tensor back.

How would one do that?

Comment: Did you try `tf.reshape(output, [-1, 32, 256, 4])`?

Comment: yes that was way easier than i expected.  btw there has to be a 2 instead of a 4 because my 4th dimension was 2. If you write that as answer Ill mark it as correct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply `reshape` to the shape you want: `tf.reshape(output, [-1, 32, 256, 2])`.